# PHP: Get data from multidimesional array to display into a select

Tags: php, arrays, select

I got this array coming from a webservice

```
array(3) { 
    ["result"]=> string(35) "Success" 
    ["item_output"]=> int(4) 
    ["output"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["code"]=> string(3) "001" 
            ["description"]=> string(23) "Product 1" 
            ["path_image"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(3) { 
            ["code"]=> string(3) "002" 
            ["description"]=> string(19) "Product 2" 
            ["path_image"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [2]=> array(3) { 
            ["code"]=> string(3) "003" 
            ["description"]=> string(17) "Product 3" 
            ["path_image"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [3]=> array(3) { 
            ["code"]=> string(3) "004" 
            ["description"]=> string(20) "Product 4" 
            ["path_image"]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

my goal is to create a select like this

```
<select name='my-select'>
<option value='001'>Product 1</option>
<option value='002'>Product 2</option>
<option value='003'>Product 3</option>
<option value='004'>Product 4</option>
</select>
```

my code at the moment is (just in regards to the select) is

```
$arr=json_decode( $resp, true );
$json=$arr['output'];
$html=array();
$html[]="<select name=''>";

foreach($json as $i => $v )
    $html[]="<option value='$i'>$v</option>";

$html[]="</select>";
```

which gives this as result

```
<select name=''>
<option value='0'>Array</option>
<option value='1'>Array</option>
<option value='2'>Array</option>
<option value='3'>Array</option>
</select>
```

does anyone know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: use `$v[description]` instead of just `$v`.

Comment: `$html[]="<option value='$i'>$v[description]</option>";` to be precise

Comment: amazing! This is what i've done `"<option value='$v[code]'>$v[description]</option>";` and the select got everything i need. Many thanks for prompt input guys

Answer (score -1):

You can write simply

```
foreach($json as $i => $v )
    $html[]="<option value='$i["code"]'>$v["description"]</option>"
```

Comment: You might like to check that code, specially the use of `"` inside a doublequouted literal :)